# I want to upload the large video files to Azure blob storage in chunks using Python PUT request using SAS urls

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

My use case is like i need to create a path in the azure blob containers for my users and their videos,I should generate a sas url for the perticular user video storage blob and  using that url i want to make the upload in chunks I bit confused in BinaryClient, BinaryService etc in Azure pythonSDKs suggest me a standard method in most secure way to upload video to azure blob using SAS urls, right now i was able to generate SAS tokens

```html
def sas_token_genetation(container_name, blob_name):
    connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={container_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=blob_service_client.account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, update = True, delete= True, list = True, add=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )
    return sas_token
```

and sas urls

```html
def sas_url(account_name : str, container_name:str , blob_name : str):
    sas_token = sas_token_genetation(container_name, blob_name)
    connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={container_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    sas_url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
    return sas_url
```

Pls check and tell me the method that i am following is correct or not also
suggest me how to continously make PUT request to the azure blob with some status codes and at the end of the chunk status is completed it should get merged all the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

> Suggest me a standard method in the most secure way to upload the video to Azure blob using SAS urls, right now I was able to generate SAS tokens

You use the below code to upload a video file with sas-url using Python.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobBlock,generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions,BlobClient
import time

def Upload_data():
    account_name="Your-account-name"
    account_key="Your-account-key"
    container_name="test"
    blob_name="sample.mp4"
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(
            read=True, write=True, delete=True, list=True, add=True
        ),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )
    url = 'https://'+account_name+'.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name+'/'+blob_name+'?'+sas_token
    print(url)
    #upload data
    start=time.time()
    block_list=[]
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(url)
    chunk_size=4*1024*1024
    with  open("C:\\video.mp4",'rb') as  f:
       while  True:
           read_data = f.read(chunk_size)
           if  not  read_data:
              break  # done
           blk_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
           blob_client.stage_block(block_id=blk_id,data=read_data)
           block_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id=blk_id))
           blob_client.commit_block_list(block_list)
           end=time.time()
           print("Time taken to upload blob:", end - start, "secs")
           print("uploaded video successfully")
Upload_data()
```

**Output:**

```
https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample.mp4?<sastoken>
Time taken to upload blob: 3.4153733253479004 secs
uploaded video successfully
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[azure.storage.blob.BlobClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#examples)

Comment: I wanted to upload files in the specific path inside the container for example 
uservideos is my container and i want to upload in uservideos/user_12/video_12/ 
path i think the above doesnot work for these scenarios,also if possible suggested me how to upload multple files to same blob uservideos/user_12/video_12/ user.txt, video.txt i want to upload multiple files in same blob path.

Comment: For uploading multiple blobs I would suggest [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) tool. it will upload more number of files to your storage account.

Comment: can that be used for uploading from my react application i think the azcopy tool is used to copy using terminal only am i correct?